# How to get a particular text out of a message with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the text CITY inside a `<p>` element with `id="demo"`

**HTML:**

```
<p id="demo">this CITY is too small</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
```

I get all the text but I only want to get CITY

Comment: What are the rules for identifying that word? Is it any text in capitals? The second word?

Comment: is the double quote on the script deliberate?

Comment: @DanielV I removed it as they said *I get all the text* - so presumably the double quote was a typo

Comment: Your parse the string you get with Javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML.split(" ")[1];
```

But this works **only** for the specified string. If for instance CITY had another position inside the string, then the result of this wouldn't have been CITY.

```js
var city = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML.split(" ")[1];
document.write(city);
```

```html
<p id="demo">this CITY is too small</p>
```